# Default selection of radio buttons not working in Angular

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular-reactive-forms

I have three radio buttons. I want to use them in Angular Reactive Forms. I am unable to trigger change event in case of default selection of any radio button. I want to default select Male radio button but change event on default selection does not fire. Please help me to figure out what wrong I am doing here.

I have tried to put the behaviour in stackbiz. Here is the link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-radio-buttons-demo-reactive-forms-kqy3vi?file=src/app/app.component.html

My component code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
  export interface Gender {
    id: number;
    value: string;
  }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent{
 public genders: Array<Gender> = [
      {'id': 1, 'value': 'Male'},
      {'id': 2, 'value': 'FeMale'},
      {'id': 3, 'value': 'Not Specified'}
    ];
  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) { }

  /*########### Form ###########*/
  registrationForm = this.fb.group({
    gender: ['', [Validators.required]]
  })
  // Getter method to access form control
  get myForm() {
    return this.registrationForm.get('gender');
  }
changeFired(e: any) {
  console.log('change fired before', e.value);
}

  // Submit Registration Form
  onSubmit() {
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.registrationForm.value));
  }  

}
```

My Html

```
<div class="container">
        <form [formGroup]="registrationForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                <!-- Gender -->
                <div>
                    <h5>Gender</h5>
                    <div>

                        <div *ngFor="let g of genders; let i = index">
                            <input id="i" type="radio" [value]="g" name="gender" formControlName="gender" (change)="changeFired(g)">
              <label>{{g.value}}</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

          <!-- Submit Button -->
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>

      </form><!-- Form ends -->
</div>
```

Comment: Component code contains HTML instead of TypeScript, please correct.

Comment: Thanks Uminder, I really didn't realize having wrong code. Sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are trying to set the value something like below

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.myForm.setValue({id:1,gender:"Male"});
  }
```

This will not set your selected radio to male because it has different reference (memory address). When it comes to complex object it is always references. You should  try something like below :

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.myForm.setValue(this.genders[0]); // this refers to male
  }
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-radio-buttons-demo-reactive-forms-orxzhs)

Comment: it only sets radiobutton checked but does not fire change event

Comment: @CredibleAshok Actually it causes change event to be fired. In my example i didn't add registration to changes. Check stackblitz again.

Comment: Thanks that was the miss I was looking for. Thanks a lot you my another day getting ruined.

Answer (score 1):

Assign a template variable to your `input` tag(s):

```
<div *ngFor="let g of genders; let i = index">
  <input 
    id="i" 
    type="radio" 
    #input
    name="gender" 
    [value]="g.id"
    formControlName="gender" 
    (change)="showMessage(g)">
  <label>{{g.value}}</label>
</div>
```

Then in your Component Class, access it using `ViewChildren`. And in the `ngAfterViewInit` dispatch a `change` event by using `dispatchEvent` on the `nativeElement` property of an appropriate item from the `QueryList`.

Doing that will throw an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenChecked` error.

So to fix that, you'll have to explicitly run the change detection again by calling `this.cdRef.detectChanges();` where `cdRed` is the `ChangeDetectorRef` that I injected as a dependency.

This is how it would translate to code:

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ViewChildren,
  ElementRef,
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  QueryList
} from "@angular/core";

...

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {

  ...

  defaultSelectedOption = 3;
  @ViewChildren("input") inputs: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  ...

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder, private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  /*########### Form ###########*/
  registrationForm = this.fb.group({
    gender: [this.defaultSelectedOption, [Validators.required]]
  });

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const inputToTrigger = this.inputs.toArray()[
      this.genders.findIndex(gender => gender.id === this.defaultSelectedOption)
    ];
    (inputToTrigger.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement).dispatchEvent(
      new Event("change")
    );
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }

  ...

}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/trigger-change-event-for-input-explicitly-in-angular) for your ref.

Comment: this ref only works if i set default as 1. does nt work for any other value